# Exporting a material+mesh list

Tags: mesh, materials, scripting, export, add-on

So I'm working on a long term project which consits a file with over 100+ Meshes. Each mesh has number of different mats assigned to it. Is it possible to export a list from Blender which provides the following info:
Mesh-Linked Materials.
Doing it manually is the last resort which i would like to avoid if there are any possibilities. Thank you in advance:)

Comment: What do you mean "export a list"?

Comment: Well certainly this is possible if you use the blender python API

Comment: Export a list as in, the information of all materials present in the file and to which meshes these are linked to. I will certainly look into API thing.